# Should a boolean predicate for std::condition_variable be volatile in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, undefined-behavior, std

I've been hearing so many conflicting answers, and now I don't know what to think.
The agreed-upon knowledge is that for sharing memory in a thread safe manner in C++, it's required to use volatile **together with** std::mutex.

Based on that understanding, I've been writing code like this:

```
volatile bool ready = false;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex mtx;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lckr{ mtx };
cv.wait(lckr, [&ready]() -> bool { return ready; });
```

But then I saw a lecture of Chandler Carruth in CppCon where he said (as a side note) that volatile is not required in this situation, and that I should basically never use volatile.

I then saw other answers in Stack Overflow that say that volatile should never be used, and it's not good enough and it doesn't guarantee atomicity at all.

Is Chandler Carruth correct? Are we both wrong?

Now I have 3 options:

1. Must use volatile or std::atomic
2. Any boolean will do
3. Must be std::atomic

I want to know if I'm allowed by the C++14 ISO standard to write code like this:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <functional>

struct sync_t
{
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mtx;
    bool ready{ false };
};
static void threaded_func(sync_t& sync)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lckr{ sync.mtx };
    sync.ready = true;
    std::cout << "Waking up main thread" << std::endl;
    sync.cv.notify_one();
}
int main()
{
    sync_t sync;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lckr{ sync.mtx };
        sync.ready = false;
        std::future<void> thread =
            std::async(std::launch::async, threaded_func, std::ref(sync));
        std::cout << "Preparing to sleep" << std::endl;
        sync.cv.wait(lckr, [&sync]() -> bool { return sync.ready; });
        thread.get();
    }
    std::cout << "Done program execution" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and what happens when I make it:

```
volatile bool ready{ false };
```

and what happens when I make it:

```
std::atomic<bool> ready{ false };
```

Comment: There are two items of Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++ related to this that may be of interest to you (39. Consider void futures for one-shot event communication, and 40. Use std::atomic for concurrency, volatile for special memory.) From my understanding, `volatile` should only be used for special memory; for concurrency with condition variables, a normal `bool` is enough; but there are better ways than a condition variable plus boolean combo: e.g. a counting semaphore with a count of 1, or a future.

Comment: "Agreed-upon knowledge"? Where? Do you have any references?

Comment: Note that the `condition_variable`'s predicate is only ever evaluated while the condition has a lock on the mutex. *"The agreed-upon knowledge is that for sharing memory in a thread safe manner in C++, it's required to use volatile together with std::mutex."* I don't know where you got this impression from, but it is not accurate. `volatile` is completely unrelated to concurrency and cannot be used to solve any concurrency problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux How does the compiler know not to "optimize-out" my plain boolean? Is it solely because there's an std::mutex being locked and it knows that the boolean might be modified by another thread? Or should I distrust the compiler and explicitly declare the boolean as volatile?

Comment: @rturrado I wrote that my question is about C++14. There only exist counting semaphores since C++20.

Comment: @Ronen `volatile` is completely unrelated to concurrency. There is basically no problem related to multithreading that can be resolved with adding `volatile`. Locking a mutex acts as a fence, the compiler has to assume that anything that might be referred externally might have been changed.

Answer (score 5):

The `volatile` qualifier has no *required* effect on access to an object from different threads – it only guarantees that no side-effects of modification in a *single* thread will be optimized-out by the compiler. [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) (bold emphasis mine):

> - **volatile object** - an object whose type is volatile-qualified, or a subobject of a volatile object, or a mutable subobject of a
>   const-volatile object. Every access (read or write operation, member
>   function call, etc.) made through a glvalue expression of
>   volatile-qualified type is treated as a visible side-effect for the
>   purposes of optimization (that is, ***within a single thread of
>   execution***, volatile accesses cannot be optimized out or reordered
>   with another visible side effect that is sequenced-before or
>   sequenced-after the volatile access. This makes volatile objects
>   suitable for communication with a signal handler, ***but not with
>   another thread of execution***, see std::memory_order). Any attempt to
>   refer to a volatile object through a glvalue of non-volatile type
>   (e.g. through a reference or pointer to non-volatile type) results in
>   undefined behavior.

To prevent undefined behaviour when accessing an object from *multiple* threads, you should use a `std::atomic` object. Again, [from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic):

> Each instantiation and full specialization of the std::atomic template
> defines an atomic type. If one thread writes to an atomic object while
> another thread reads from it, the behavior is well-defined (see memory
> model for details on data races).
>
> In addition, accesses to atomic objects may establish inter-thread
> synchronization and order non-atomic memory accesses as specified by
> std::memory_order.

Comment: Is `std::atomic` still needed even though `bool ready` flag is guarded by `std::mutex` in this case?

Comment: @pptaszni Probably not  so long as all accesses are preceded with a `lock_guard`. But OP was also asking a more general question about what `volatile` does.

Comment: Which std::memory_order would I use in the situation that's described in my question?
Do I even need to use std::atomic<bool> in this situation (since it's guarded by a std::mutex)?

Comment: @Ronen See my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

No, volatile is confusing keyword but it has nothing to do with concurrency unlike in C# or Java where it guarantees sequential consistency. Here its just a hint to the compiler not to optimise the variable.

Comment: It's a wee bit more than a "hint" - for a single thread, it's a *guarantee* that side effects of access won't be optimized away.

Answer (score 1):

I now know more since I asked the question.
The answer is that Chandler Carruth is correct that a regular bool (with a std::mutex) is enough. No need for atomic, and no need for volatile.
"volatile" should only be used when dealing with signal handlers, like this:

```
volatile std::sig_atomic_t
```

Contrary to popular belief, the C++ compile isn't allowed to just "optimize-out" your read from a boolean when you're using a std::mutex. That's because locking the mutex acts as a "fence" and after the mutex is locked the compiler has to assume that variables could have changed. The compiler can still optimize-out local variables that it can prove not to have changed, but in my example of using a boolean as a predicate, I send the boolean by reference to another function:

```
std::future<void> thread =
        std::async(std::launch::async, threaded_func, std::ref(sync));
```

The boolean exists inside of "sync" and therefore now the compiler isn't allowed to assume that the value stays the same. The compile can still store the boolean value in a register, but the moment I lock the std::mutex it'll be forced to reload the value because it could have changed.
Of course (according to the standard) the function std::condition_variable::wait keeps the std::mutex locked when it returns, so it'll always be checking the boolean predicate when the std::mutex is locked, deeming the entire thing safe.

So in summary: volatile is not required for multithreading, ever. And std::mutex is enough.

The answer to my question is that the code I wrote with a plain boolean is safe, and all three options would also be safe. Using volatile would be safe, and using std::atomic would be safe. But using a regular boolean would be the most correct and efficient in this situation.
In fact, if you have a lock (std::mutex) you never need std::atomic.
It's important to note that if I didn't make an effort to use a std::mutex every time I read from the predicate then std::atomic **would be required**.

I took this knowledge from the various answers that were given to my question here, and I also tested this in Compiler Explorer with Clang13. It would be interesting to see proofs from the C++14 standard.

Answer (score 0):

volatile simply tell the compiler that someone may change this value even if you don't know who, for example, it may be some hardware, signal, or even other thread.
A famous example is:

```
bool flag
 foo()
 {
   flag = true;
   while(flag)
   {
   }
 }
```

optimized compiler will see that flag is true and since its only a normal global variable it can assume that no one can change it except the current thread, so the compiler may assume that flag is always true, and hence switch the `while(flag)` to `while(1)` to make an infinite loop.
but if you declare the flag variable as volatile, the compiler can't assume that only the current thread touches this value, so the code will remain the same.

now for your question, the volatile will help us notify the compiler that someone else may use this value, but it does not enough to multi-threading since it does not prevent a data race which is undefined behavior in c language, hence we need to declare the bool flag as std::atomic.

note that one of the things that the compiler understands from std::atomic declaration is that another thread may use this value so we can't make the optimization above.

for your example, as we explained, volatile is not enough, but you do not need std::atomic either since you have a lock, so if your lock works right then no other thread may touch the value when you are inside the critical section so std::atomic is redundant.

std::atomic is mainly for a critical section when all the critical section is because of atomic operations, so we can use std::atomic instead take a lock which is slower(its not always the case, it depends on the flow).

Comment: Your answer is what I used to think. Pretty much everyone else in this thread has answered that if I use a std::mutex correctly then I'm allowed to use a regular boolean, and the compiler is not allowed to optimize that. That's why I asked this question here, I know a lot about concurrency in C++ but I don't know the rules about when the compiler is allowed to optimize-out my plain boolean.

Comment: regarding concurrency, if you  dont use declaration such as atomic or volatile, the compiler assume that the no one touches this variable so he can do whatever optimization he wants regarding the variable(save it in register, remove re read of the variable, re read the variable again and so on) thats why it is important  to declare variable as std atomic even if you know the platform that the code will run on(x86 for example, so you can say that simple mov is atomic) and if you dont care from the memory order you may say thats ok, bool is atomic, but it is data race in c

Comment: so the compiler can optimize your code inside the mutex!! and you can even try the while loop i showed here with a mutex and see if you compile it with o2 the compiler will make an infinite loop, but that does not matter, since there is a lock theoretically no one will change the flag value so it is infinite loop!

Comment: Moshe, you should look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70909085/7753444 Chandler Carruth did say that it took him a while to convince his colleagues at Google that the predicate shouldn't be volatile. They were saying: "but we've been doing it this way for years!"

Comment: i did not say it should, but it is not right that the compiler do not optimize variables inside the mutex critical section, and you can check it.

Comment: Moshe. As I said in my answer: the compiler is allowed to omit reloading values after "enter critical section" if and only if it can prove that the value in question couldn't have been changed by another thread. Here's proof with your example in Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/Exd69cdWj (checks flag only once because no mutex), https://godbolt.org/z/j13a6x6TT (reloads flag each time because of mutex). Your example had to be changed a little bit because your example code has no effect, so the compiler will optimize it regardless (doesn't return anything, doesn't do anything).

Comment: the compiler assume that the code is single threaded unless you told him otherwise, so it should not prove that another thread cant use it in normal variable. regarding the second example, the compiler reload the flag since it does not know if the lock function changed the flag, but if you put the mutex before the initiliaztion of the flag, it wont reload it again(you can try to switch the lock with some other library function such as printf and it wont optimize the flag). i say that the compiler can optimize variables inside the critical section but its fine to do so if your mutex works well.

Comment: Did you mean C++ when you said C?

Comment: Moshe, just as you said. The compiler reloads the flag in the second example because it doesn't know if the lock function could have changed the flag. If I would call a custom function using a function pointer (that the compiler can't discern at compile time) then it would have the same effect (not optimizing, because the function could have changed the value). That's guaranteed behavior and therefore no need for volatile when dealing with multithreading, ever.